# Plotly - Points not appearing on 3d Plot

Tags: python, plotly

I have been trying to plot a 3d plot in Plotly.

`fig = go.Figure(data = [go.Surface(z=y_test[:, 0], x = X_test['GDP per capita'].values, y = X['Generosity'].values)]) fig.show()`

The three arrays I am passing in are all of length 39. They all have correct values in them.  However, my plot shows the colorbar and no plot.  What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Are the data frames in the 3-dimensional array different data frames for x, y, and z, respectively? Typo.

Comment: yes, they are.  I then used the .values to extract arrays to make sure I had no issues with this.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the kernel? Sometimes it can stop plotting and only colorbars appear.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that as well.  Only the colorbar.  I am perplexed.